# How to check if each sheet has listed name

Tags: excel, vba

When I set following code, I'd like to filter in array content.

So I would like to filter named `test1` and `sheet1` sheet

I developed sample script as follows

But it returned wrong type does not match in `If ws.Name Like list Then`

```
Dim list as variant

list = Array("test1", "sheet1")

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
  If ws.Name Like list Then
  
  End If
next
```

How to avoid this error ?

And how can I filter sheets ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Would just add or statement inside and don't go with list. Or try to use Application.Match `Application.Match(Sheets(i).Name, list, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub a()

List = Array("test1", "sheet1")

x = Application.Match("test1", List, 0)

If IsError(x) Then
    Debug.Print "Not Found"
Else
    Debug.Print "Found at position " & x
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Filtering by showing only listed sheets**

> How can I filter sheets?

a) To find equivalent names you can check if `Application.Match()` returns an error for non-findings via `IsError` (or alternatively if there are findings via `IsNumeric`). Note that matching is case independant.

b) Eventually you can set the worksheet' s `.Visible` property to

- `True` (i.e. `xlSheetVisible`) or
- `False` (i.e. `xlSheetHidden`).

```
Sub ShowOnlyListedSheets()
    Dim list As Variant
    list = Array("test1", "sheet1")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, list, 0)) Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden           ' or: False
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible          ' or: True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```